# Is Multivariate regression(multiple target variables) using neural networks a trivial task?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, regression

Is Multivariate regression using neural networks as easy as having "n" output nodes in the final layer of the neural network? ("n" would be the number of target variables)

I have read conflicting accounts about it. Such as Regressor Stacking, Regressor Chains as opposed to having more nodes in the output layer of a neural net.

Answer (score 1):

The whole field of object detection more or less works this way.You want to predict boxes around objects in e.g. images. For every box you essentially predict multiple regression parameters like x, y position, width and length. In 3D object detection you haven even more parameters like z position, height, rotation (yaw angle).

I don't know if I would call it trivial but definitely works.

As with many things in machine learning you never know if you don't try. What can work on one task might not work as good on another one. In general I would always start the the easiest solution, which in your case is probably just adding another neuron to your output layer and see how that works.

Comment: Yup, thanks. I've tried out adding more neurons (output layer), and it's giving me interesting results. Will try out the other methods too.